# Display <IPython.core.display.HTML object> in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, ipython, databricks

I am trying to display Spacy Dependency Tree in Pyspark (Databricks). But I am getting this error.
Could someone help me with the display of html object please.
I am attaching screenshot of the Error message. Thanks in advance.
Here is my code:

```
import spacy
from spacy import displacy

doc = nlp("Reliance is looking at buying U.K. based analytics startup for $7 billion")
displacy.render(doc, style="dep" , jupyter=True)
```

Error message:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This won't work in the Databricks notebooks, because it's not an Jupyter.  But you can use [displayHTML function](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/visualizations/html-d3-and-svg.html) together with rendering as [HTML](https://spacy.io/usage/visualizers#html):

```py
displayHTML(displacy.render(doc, style="dep", page=True))
```

Or even display SVG data directly:

```
displayHTML(displacy.render(doc, style="dep"))
```

here is result:

[image]

Comment: wow, it worked :) Thanks for the solution and explanation. Appreciate it